# Ignoring a character along with word boundary in regex

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I am using gsub in Ruby to make a word within text bold.  I am using a word boundary so as to not make letters within other words bold, but am finding that this ignores words that have a quote after them.  For example:

```
text.gsub(/#{word}\b/i, "<b>#{word}</b>")

text = "I said, 'look out below'"
word = below
```

In this case the word below is not made bold.  Is there any way to ignore certain characters along with a word boundary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that escaping in the `Regexp.new` is looking quite ugly. You could greatly simplify that by using a Regexp literal:

```
word = 'below'
text = "I said, 'look out below'"

reg = /\b#{word}\b/i
text.gsub!(reg, '<b>\0</b>')
```

Also, you could use the modifier form of `gsub!` directly, unless that string is aliased in some other place in your code that you are not showing us. Lastly, if you use the single quoted string literal inside your `gsub` call, you don't need to escape the backslash.

Answer (score 2):

Be **very** careful with your `\b` boundaries.  [Here’s why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213800/is-there-something-like-a-counter-variable-in-regular-expression-replace/4214173#4214173).

Answer (score -1):

The `#{word}` syntax doesn't work for regular expressions. Use [`Regexp.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Regexp.html#M001198) instead:

```
word = "below"
text = "I said, 'look out below'"

reg = Regexp.new("\\b#{word}\\b", true)
text = text.gsub(reg, "<b>\\0</b>")
```

Note that when using sting you need to escape `\b` to `\\b`, or it is interpreted as a backspace. If `word` may contain special regex characters, escape it using `Regexp.escape`.

Also, by replacing the string to `<b>#{word}</b>` you may change casing of the string: "BeloW" will be replaced to "below". `\0` corrects this by replacing with the found word. In addition, I added `\\b` at the beginning, you don't want to look for "**day**" and end up with "sun**day**".

Comment: This is a proud moment for me - my first ever Ruby! I tested the code using http://www.ruby.ch/interpreter/rubyinterpreter.shtml , and referred the apparently useful docs.

Comment: Ok thanks.  However, I am using Ruby, and would rather stick to using the gsub method.  I use #{word} to pass the word that I am trying to highlight.  So in this example, word = 'below'