# Ruby regex gsub a line in a text file

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I need to match a line in an inputted text file string and wrap that captured line with a character for example.

For example imagine a text file as such:

```
test
foo
test
bar
```

I would like to use gsub to output:

```
XtestX
XfooX
XtestX
XbarX
```

I'm having trouble matching a line though.  I've tried using regex starting with ^ and ending with $, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

I have a text file that has the following in it:

```
test
foo
test
bag
```

The text file is being read in as a command line argument.

So I got

```
string = IO.read(ARGV[0])
string = string.gsub(/^(test)$/,'X\1X')

puts string
```

It outputs the exact same thing that is in the text file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code you've applied to the problem, and all **relevant** error messages exactly as they appear.

Comment: use word boundaries, i.e. `\b` see e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902004/ignoring-a-character-along-with-word-boundary-in-regex)

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to match *every* line, then

```
gsub(/^.*$/, 'X\&X')
```

does the trick.  If you only want to match certain lines, then replace `.*` with whatever you need.

**Update:**

Replacing your `gsub` with mine:

```
string = IO.read(ARGV[0])
string = string.gsub(/^.*$/, 'X\&X')
puts string
```

I get:

```
$ gsub.rb testfile
XtestX
XfooX
XtestX
XbarX
```

**Update 2:**

As per @CodeGnome, you might try adding `chomp`:

```
IO.readlines(ARGV[0]).each do |line|
  puts "X#{line.chomp}X"
end
```

This works equally well for me.  My understanding of `^` and `$` in regular expressions was that chomping wouldn't be necessary, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes it does.  Please post the code you're actually working with.

Comment: If you replace your `gsub` with mine, it works.  I just tried it.

Comment: No it doesn't.  It outputs

Xtest
Xfoo
Xbar
Xtest

Comment: @Tommy In your code you have: `.gsub(/^(test)$/,'X\1X')` Not `.gsub(/^.*$/, 'X\&X')` as @darshan's code.  Notice the `X\1X` vs `X\&X`

Comment: Both ways do not work.  \1 matches whatever is in the parentheses.

Comment: I copied exactly what you have and I keep getting 
Xtest
Xfoo
Xbar
Xtest

Comment: Well wtf.  I literally copied and pasted that and I get Xtest Xfoo Xbar Xtest on separate lines.  I'm using Ruby 1.9.3?

Comment: a = <<-eos
test
foo
eos
a = a.gsub(/^.*$/, 'X\&X')
p a # "XtestX\nXfooX\n"

Comment: @Tommy, I suspect something is very goofy with your input file.  Perhaps create a new one, copied and pasted from here?  Honestly, though, I can't think of what's going on that you're matching and getting the first `X` but not the second one.

Comment: Ya I've tried making different text files.  It's a simple .txt file.  And ya that's precisely why I'm asking this.  I don't get it.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in one line like this:

```
IO.write(filepath, File.open(filepath) {|f| f.read.gsub(//<appId>\d+<\/appId>/, "<appId>42</appId>"/)})
```

`IO.write` truncates the given file by default, so if you read the text first, perform the regex `String.gsub` and return the resulting string using `File.open` in block mode, it will replace the file's content in one fell swoop.

I like the way this reads, but it can be written in multiple lines too of course:

```
IO.write(filepath, File.open(filepath) do |f|
    f.read.gsub(//<appId>\d+<\/appId>/, "<appId>42</appId>"/)
  end
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your file is `input.txt`, I'd do as following

```
File.open("input.txt") do |file|
  file.lines.each do |line|
    puts line.gsub(/^(.*)$/, 'X\1X')
  end
end
```

- `(.*)` allows to capture any characters and makes it a variable Regexp
- `\1` in the string replacement is that captured group

If you prefer to do it in one line on the whole content, you can do it as following

```
 File.read("input.txt").gsub(/^(.*)$/, 'X\1X')
```

Comment: So you're saying you can't match lines in a single string...?

Comment: @Tommy Yes, it is possible. I've added another option if you prefer to do it on the whole content.

Comment: Does this work with the text file as a command line argument?

Comment: Yes, it does: `puts File.read(ARGV[0]).gsub(/^(.*)$/, 'X\1X')` and do `ruby your_script.rb input.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

`string.gsub(/^(matchline)$/, 'X\1X')`
Uses a backreference (\1) to get the first capture group of the regex, and surround it with X

Example:

```
string = "test\nfoo\ntest\nbar"
string.gsub!(/^test$/, 'X\&X')
p string
=> "XtestX\nfoo\nXtestX\nbar"
```

Comment: I tried string.gsub(/^(test)$/,'X\1X') and it does not work.  That is the problem I'm having?

Comment: Perhaps you didn't include the !, at the end of gsub! to apply it in-place, try `p string.gsub(/^(test)$/, 'X\1X')`

Comment: My text file is read in through IO as an command line argument.  Does it automatically put \n's in it?  Because that regex does not work.

Comment: If you are reading straight from argf maybe you need to use the .read method on it, this works: http://ideone.com/8jxyzT

Comment: The problem is with your string input, show us the exact string you are parsing to find the problem. (`print IO.read(ARGV[0])`)

Comment: Printing what you said displays exactly what I showed above test foo test bar on separate lines.

Comment: Try this: `string.gsub(/^test\r?\n/, 'X\&X')` it recognizes carriage returns.

Answer (score 0):

### Chomp Line Endings

Your lines probably have newline characters. You need to handle this one way or another. For example, this works fine for me:

```
$ ruby -ne 'puts "X#{$_.chomp}X"' /tmp/corpus
XtestX
XfooX
XtestX
XbarX
```