# how to replace a line having a specific string in a file [ruby]

Tags: ruby, file

I just started learning Ruby.

I need to replace some lines in a file, which are having a specific string in it.

How to append the file using Ruby?

I have tried different approaches, including:

```
file_names.each do |file_name|
    text = File.read(file_name)
    puts text.gsub(/search_regexp/, "replace string")
end
```

Comment: Are you trying to replace the filename?  File.read will get you the file contents.  You may want to loop each line then?  Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991858/ruby-regex-gsub-a-line-in-a-text-file

Answer (score 1):

To make the replacing permanent you would have to write the file back to disk

```
read = File.read(file).gsub(/search_regexp/, "replace string")
File.write(file, read)
```